# Many-to-many relationship JPA - unique constraint

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 entities, Event and Tag, in a many-to-many relationship. Tags should have unique names, so I placed a constraint on it.

It works like expected for unique tag names, I save a batch of new events and entries are automatically inserted in the tag and join tables.

But the moment I try to save an event that has a tag with a duplicate name, an error is thrown due to it violating the constraint.

Is there a way around this that does not involve having to check and insert all the events/tags manually?

Code below:

Event entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
class Event {

    @Id long id;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "event_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    // other properties
}
```

Tag entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Tag {

    @Id long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Event> events;
}
```

I'm using `JpaRepository`'s method `saveAll` to persist the events. It throws:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Duplicate entry 'xxxxx' for key 'uq_tag_name'
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readErrorPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1694) ~[mariadb-java-client-2.7.3.jar:na]
```

I have seen a few similar questions but have yet to find a working answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

it happen because of { CascadeType.ALL }
when you set CascadeType.ALL hibernate changes the Tag table and if it need,insert data for Tag.you should remove CascadeType.ALL and if you get (cannot insert transient object) should use flush for handlinf that